# JSTL <c:forEach> not supports List<Integer>?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

```
                            ${test}
                             <c:forEach items=" ${test}" var="sharedType">
                                  ${sharedType}<br/>
                                 <c:if test="${sharedType == 2}" >
                                     <span class="tweet-button"></span>
                                 </c:if>
                                 <c:if test="${sharedType == 1}" >
                                     TEST
                                     <a href="#" class="fbshare-button">Share</a>
                                 </c:if>
                            </c:forEach>
```

The integer list is 1,2,3. 
On my page, it show [1,2,3] for ${test}, and "[1" "2" "3" for ${sharedType} in 3 iterations. Looks like JSTL think it is a String separated by comma rather than a list. 
The code to generate the list in java is:

```
List<Integer> test= new ArrayList<Integer>();
            test.add(1);
            test.add(2);
            test.add(3);
```

I have been struggling with this for a while, can anyone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Try removing space in `" ${test}"`.

Comment: add you using the jstl version that evaluates the ${} notation itself (if I recall correctly it is jstl-rt), or is the jsp evaluating it for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just checked it in my app and so put it as an answer: try removing space from `items=" ${test}"`. Otherwise, you're executing equivalent of this java expression `" " + testList`. Obviously, the result is not a list.

*and "[1" "2" "3" for ${sharedType} in 3 iterations*
Most likely there was only one iteration and you're seeing the result of `test.toString()` call.